# Is it correct to say "like a look for a needle" or should it use "looking"?

Tags: idioms, syntax

Is the following sentence wrong?

> He had lost a ring in the sand and I help him search for it but it was **like a look for a needle in a haystack**.

To me it sounds very awkward, though "look" means **"the act of trying to find someone or something."**

I think **"it was like looking for a needle in a haystack"** would be correct.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But you need to correct **help** to **helped**.

Comment: I have edited your question. When you post something, make sure to add proper punctuation, particularly a *question mark* and a *period*. You also added the emphasis (bold type) incorrectly, which I have corrected.

Answer (score 1):

This is an idiom and the idiom is "looking for a needle...".  The noun "look" tends to be used in the expression "have a look".

As the idiom is "looking" and you are not using "have a look", you are right that the first sentence is awkward, and you should use "like looking for a needle in a haystack".  As noted in a comment it should be "helped" for the past tense here.

Comment: In my dialect, by the way, *have a look* is less usual than *take a look*.